# Is the GNS-vector associated to a tracial state cyclic for the commutant?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra and $\tau\in A^*$ a tracial state. Let $(\pi_\tau, H_\tau, \xi_\tau)$ be the associated GNS-representation. Is it true that $\pi_\tau(A)'\xi_\tau$ is dense in $H_\tau$?

Note that $\xi_\tau$ is separating for $\pi_\tau(A)$ by the traciality assumption.

In particular, if $\tau$ is normal, then $\pi_\tau(A)$ is a von Neumann algebra and the result follows.

If $\tau$ is faithful I can also finish.

Is this true for a general tracial state?

Context: This is used in the proof of theorem 6.1.4 in Brown Ozawa's book "C*-algebras and finite-dimensional approximations".

Comment: ok, silly question here, why does traciality imply that $\xi_\tau$ is separating for $\pi_{\tau}(A)$? I do not doubt it; just looking for a brief explanation.

Comment: @Condo Still looking for an explanation? I can provide it then.

Comment: yes that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this works is because you are doing GNS for the trace (it is not true in general, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93295/separating-vectors-for-c-algebras)). When you do GNS for a trace, separating for $\pi_\tau(A)$ implies separating for $\pi_\tau(A)''$.

Let $x\in\pi_\tau(A)''$ with $x\xi_\tau=0$. Then there exists a net $\{a_j\}\subset A$ with $\pi_\tau(a_j)\to x$ sot. For any $b\in A$,
\begin{align}
\langle \pi_\tau(a_j)\pi_\tau( b)\xi_\tau,\pi_\tau( b)\xi_\tau\rangle
&=\langle \pi_\tau(b^*a_jb)\xi_\tau,\xi_\tau\rangle=\tau(b^*a_jb)=\tau(bb^*a_j)\\[0.3cm]
&
=\langle \pi_\tau(a_j)\xi_\tau,\pi_\tau(bb^*)\xi_\tau\rangle\to\langle x\xi_\tau,\pi_\tau(bb^*)\xi_\tau\rangle=0.
\end{align}
As $\pi_\tau( A)\xi_\tau$ is dense, this shows that $a_j\to0$ wot. That is, $x=0$.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow. I know this fact for von Neumann algebras, but why is it true for general C*-algebras? By your observation: $\xi_\tau$ is cyclic for $\pi_\tau(A)'$ iff $\xi_\tau$ is separating for $\pi_\tau(A)''$ but I only know it is separating for $\pi_\tau(A)$.

Comment: You are totally. It works because it is a trace. Please see the edit.

Comment: Thanks for the help!